# vscode see error messages without hovering

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode, I have a python linter setup which helps me identify if there are any errors in my code, by underlining the error prone section with red swiggly lines. I can see the error message, if I hover over that section. Is there a keyboard shortcut which can show the error message, without actually requiring me to hover.

Attaching a screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is called "Show Hover" (`editor.action.showHover`).

By default is bound to <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`K`</kbd> <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd>. (Last character here is upper case letter "i", if even code renders illegible sans-serif.)

(Or you can find it in and invoke it from the Command Palette.)

---

I too wasn't able to find it at first, because "hover" was not therm I'd search for. 'Mouse', 'cursor', 'tooltip', 'hint', 'info', 'bubble' or 'popup' were.

Comment: thanks for sharing the command, but seems like it doesn't work very well [vim extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim)

Comment: There is some discussion about Vim extension/mode in the linked question.

Comment: ignore the comment, it is working fine, I was trying with wrong pattern.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [Error Lens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) to display error messages at the end of each line with an error.